# Админка wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста можно как нибудь улучшить админку wp для работы с записями. Например у меня 179 категорий, подкатегорий и подподкатегорий. Запись идет во все 179 категории...В админке нет галочки выделить все категории и еще окошко крохотное, я должна 179 раз ставить галочку. А записей намечается для заполнения 200-300. Как нибудь можно облегчить страдания и улучшить админку для работы с записями, хотябы чекбокс с выделить все категории и то было бы счастье. Искала, гуглила, ничего подобного не нашла(

Comment: >Запись идет во все 179 категории. Это говорит что ты не правильно используешь ВП. Или скорее всего создана не правильная структура сайта.

Comment: Ну спасибо. )) Мне надо выделить все 179 категорий, под категорий и под под категорий, что тут не правильного?) Если с двух категорий надо убрать галочки это проще чем наоборот..

Comment: Всё не правильно. При правильной структуре сайта такая задач не может возникнуть. А "решение" этой задачи может повлечь большие проблемы.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, это такой проект, заказчик хочет все посты во всех категориях и чтоб посты крутились в случайном порядке, вот такая каша)))

Comment: Если заказчик хочет неправильно - задача вебмастера объяснить ему недопустимость такого подхода и риски. *И взять "много денег" за корявость таких хотелок, если не образумится. :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен с комментарием @SeVlad, что рубрики используются, скорее всего, неправильно.
Тем не менее, по технике это можно довольно просто сделать в консоли инструментов
разработчика Google Chrome (открывается по F12).

Введите команду наподобие этой в консоль и нажмите Enter. Возможно, потребуется уточнение селекторов.

```
document.querySelector('#edit-1 > td > div > fieldset.inline-edit-col-center.inline-edit-categories > div > ul').querySelectorAll('input').forEach((x)=>x.checked = true)
```

Данный скрипт выбирает нужную область, где размещены рубрики для выбора, затем выбирает все инпуты внутри этой области и проставляет в них чеки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, я попробовала и почему то не сработало. Сейчас вышлю скрин.

Comment: почему то не могу тут скрин выслать

Comment: @ВикторияФайн вы можете добавить изображение в вопрос, нажав под ним кнопку [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1561963/edit)

Comment: да, я конечно высылала таким способом, но мне почему то не дает выслать, сейчас попробовала и снова не дает(((

Comment: главное свой вопрос тоже не дает отредактировать((

Comment: Благодарю за поддержку, я нашла решение, установила плагин который дает возможность дублировать пост и там всё сохраняется, все галочки мои)) Я сама от этого проекта в шоке, но так захотел заказчик, во всех категория все посты))))